# how to fix xampp apache can't run after copy php_pthreads.dll on windows 7

Tags: xampp, pthreads

how to fix my apache after copy file php_pthreads.dll for activate phpthreads in php 7.2.9 but pthreads is run, this error

```
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing 
dependencies, 
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another 
method.
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
5:06:34 PM  [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error logs, it may have something like this:

> "The apache2handler SAPI is not supported by pthreads".

If that's the case, don't use `pthreads` in combination with Apache. Try use php command line `interface(cli)`, because pthreads is cli only.